# Postback on ajax request only smartphone and tablet

Tags: c#, ajax, postback

I wrote some code in a contact form in jquery to validate the form, and if the form is valid, send all data to another file that send email with all data, etc.
Now if i use that form on PC it works, but if I use the form on a tablet or a smartphone, both android and ios, my site does postback and the validate is ignored.

Here is the part of code that validates the form

```
$('#bottone_invia_messaggio').on("click", function () {

    $("#formPrincipale").validate({

        submitHandler: function () {
            $('#bottone_invia_messaggio').val("Loading")
            var urlContatti = "url of a site";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlContatti,
                success: function () {
                    $('#bottone_invia_messaggio').val("Messaggio inviato");
                    $('#bottone_invia_messaggio').addClass("btn-success");
                    $('#bottone_invia_messaggio').prop('disabled', true);
                    inviaContatto($("#Nome").val(), $("#Email").val(), $("#Telefono").val(), $("#Messaggio").val());
                    registraEmailDb($("#Email").val());
                }
            });


        },
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        rules: {
            ctl00$Nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            ctl00$Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            ctl00$Telefono: {
                required: true
            },
            ctl00$Messaggio: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            ctl00$Privacy: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            ctl00$Nome: {
                required: "Per favore inserisci il nome",
                minlength: "Sembra troppo corto"
            },
            ctl00$Email: {
                required: "Indicaci la tua email",
                email: "Email non valida"
            },
            ctl00$Telefono: {
                required: "Inserisci un numero di telefono"
            },
            ctl00$Messaggio: {
                required: "",
                minlength: "Il messaggio e' troppo corto"
            },
            ctl00$Privacy: {
                required: "***"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (!$(element).parent().is("span")) error.insertBefore(element);
            else error.insertAfter($(element).parent());


        },
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("valid").addClass("has-error");
            $(element).removeClass("valid");

        },
        success: function (element) {
            if (!($(element).parent().is("span") || $(element).is("span"))) $(element).parent().removeClass("has-error").addClass("valid");
            console.log($(element).parent());
        }
    });
    $("#formPrincipale").attr("novalidate", "");

});
```

Here is the part of html generated server-side by asp.net

```
<div id="Contatti" class="formContatti"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="mb-1"><input name="ctl00$Nome" id="Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome e Cognome*" type="text"></div><div class="mb-1"><input name="ctl00$Email" id="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Indirizzo Email*" type="text"></div><div class="mb-1"><input name="ctl00$Telefono" id="Telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono*" type="text"></div></div><div class="col-lg-6"><textarea name="ctl00$Messaggio" rows="2" cols="20" id="Messaggio" class="form-control h-100" placeholder="Messaggio*"></textarea></div></div><div class="col-12 mt-1 text-left"><span><input id="Privacy" name="ctl00$Privacy" type="checkbox"><label for="Privacy">*Accetto i termini sulla <a class="no-decoration" href="/privacy-terms">privacy</a></label></span></div><div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse"><button id="bottone_invia_messaggio" class="btn coloreTasto mt-2">Invia il messaggio</button></div></div>
```

Sorry if I don't post all the code but there are a lot of sensitive data and is very long. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I assume that is generated though from the PC?  Have you inspected any output from what gets generated from mobile?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that what gets output as far as from a generation standpoint might be outputting a different name, which is a challenge with ASP.NET (since  you have no control).  If your JS code is defined within the ASPX, you can guarantee a match by use the `<%= %>` notation with a combination of the UniqueID of the control, as the following:

```
rules: {
    <%= Nome.UniqueID %>: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
    },
    <%= Email.UniqueID %>: {
            required: true,
            email: true
    },
    ...
```

The syntax

```
<%= Email.UniqueID %>
```

outputs a matching generated name, which may be a part of the problem.  It may say (in visual studio) that there is a formatting error in the JS, but this shouldn't have any problem on execution since it will guarantee a matching name.

Comment: i'll try it but im sure that the selector are unique, beacause i try all the selector in javascript console if there is an error before search it